# Simplify $2(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - 3(\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x) + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here is the expression:

> $$2(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - 3(\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x) + 1$$

The exercise is to evaluate it. 
In my text book the answer is $0$
I tried to factor the expression, but it got me nowhere.

Comment: What is the expression equal to? Right now it's just an expression, not an equation; there's no meaningful way to solve it.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The exercise is to evaluate the expression, the answer in my textbook is 0.

Comment: Evaluate it for what value of $x$?

Comment: @DylanSp: I expect that the result follows for all values $x$...

Comment: so you actually want to investigate the function $f(x)=2(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - 3(\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x) + 1$

Comment: I will translate exactly the words from my textbook, since it isn't in eng. 
The value of the expression (from the answer) is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x=(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x$$
$$\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x=(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)^3-3\sin^2 x\cos^2 x(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)=1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

Thus your expression simplifies to

$$2-6\sin^2x\cos^2x-3+6\sin^2x\cos^2x+1$$

Which is $0$, for all $x$.

Comment: This is it, I will give you best answer when I can(~7 mins). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

$$2(\sin^6x +\cos^6x) - 3(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)+1=$$
$$=2(\sin^2x +\cos^2x)(\sin^4x-\sin^2x \cos^2 x+\cos^4x) - 3(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)+1=$$
$$=2(\sin^4x-\sin^2x \cos^2 x+\cos^4x) - 3(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)+1=$$
$$=-2\sin^2x \cos^2 x -\sin^4x-\cos^4x+1=$$
$$-(\sin^2x +\cos^2x)^2+1=-1+1=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=\sin^2(x)$.

$$2(t^3+(1-t)^3)-3(t^2+(1-t)^2)+1=6t^2-6t+2-6t^2+6t-3+1=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right)^3\\
&=\sin^6(x)+3\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x)+3\sin^2(x)\cos^4(x)+\cos^6(x)\\
&=\sin^6(x)+3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)+\cos^6(x)\tag{1}\\\\
1
&=\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right)^2\\
&=\sin^4(x)+2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)+\cos^4(x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $3$ times $(2)$ from $2$ times $(1)$ gives $-1$. Therefore,
$$
2\left(\sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x)\right)-3\left(\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)\right)+1=0\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$ and $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$. For $a=\sin^2x$ and $b=\cos^2x$ we have
$$
2(\sin^6x+\cos^6x)-3(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)+1=
2(a+b)^3-6ab(a+b)-3(a+b)^2+6ab+1
$$
However, $a+b=\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, so the expression simplifies to
$$
2-6ab-3+6ab+1=0
$$