# prove the algebraic relation without using trig

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If

EDIT 1:

typo edited

$$ 2 (x^6 + y^6 ) - 3(x^4 + y^4 )  + (x^2+y^2) = 0,$$

then show that

$$ (x^2+y^2) =1 $$

The trigonometric converse is known already.

Comment: This is the converse of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Seeing as this question seemingly stemmed from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710182/simplify-2-sin6x-cos6x-3-sin4-x-cos4-x-1 , maybe the statement isn't true beyond the range of the trig functions?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I fail to see any connections, please say how so.

Comment: If true fo trig it is true for polynomial also, right? no matter its source/origin...

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False. $2(x^6+y^6)-3(x^4+y^4)+(x^2+y^2)=(x^2+y^2-1)(2x^4+2y^4-2x^2y^2-x^2-y^2)$ which explains why the reverse is true. Take $x=y=0$ then given relation is true and $x^2+y^2=0$.